# iCloud container default vs custom

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I am adding iCloud Core Data sync to an to an already released app. I am confused about the difference between default and custom container.

What I have learned from testing:

When I use default container my app stores the data in iCloud but it does not sync it across different devices. So let´s say I have my app on an iPhone (device A). When I use default container I can delete my app, reinstall it, do iCLoud sync and the previously saved data in iCloud is restored. So it works like a backup in iCloud. But what does not work is, that it syncs the data across different devices like from iPhone (device A) to another device for example an iPad (device B).

When I use custom container instead, it does sync across different devices. It is working like I want it to work. My data is synced across different devices and I have same data on iPhone (device A) and iPad (device B).

That is what I learned from just testing it out. But meanwhile my account seems really messed up from all the testing and deleting and wiping off iCloud data from the device and so and since you can not delete containers and do kind of fresh install it is really bit messed up. And I am confused about documentary. It says somethig like use custom containers if multiple apps share same container. But does multiple apps mean he same app on different devices? Or do they mean really different apps?

Am I right? Is that the difference of default vs custom containers?

So when I want to sync the same app across different devices I have to go with custom container?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

I had (still have) the same kind of problem. I really need only one container which my app use for synchronising between many devices. After using the default (iCloud and bundleID named container) and failing synchronisation with my setup. I reverted to testing the previous (app used a team prefixed container before) "custom" container and it looks like I am able to do all synchronisation testing I need.

Results seem to differ depending on testing setup (devices only, combination, only simulator). iCloud testing should always be devices exclusively since they are setup to act differently (non greedy unlike the simulator). All you want is real world results anyway.

My limited setup consists of one (free) app on a device and a simulator using iCloud with iCloud Drive migrated account (iOS 8.4). The synchronisation going on in my case is this:

With default container iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier):
Device <-> iCloud (All data)
Simulator <-> iCloud (Can only see simulator created data)

With custom container $(TeamIdentifier)$(CFBundleIdentifier):
Device <-> iCloud (All data)
Simulator <-> iCloud (All data)

According to the iCloud Design Guide:
"When you enable the iCloud Documents or CloudKit capability, Xcode configures your app to access the iCloud container whose name is based on the app’s bundle ID. Most apps should only need access to the default container. If your apps share data among each other, enable the “Specify custom container identifiers” option and add one or more container IDs
that you use to share data. When an app has access to multiple container IDs, the first ID in the access list is special because it is the app’s primary iCloud container."

As I understand it, each app has its own default container (the name is based on the apps bundleID). For example:
iCloud.com.company.myApp_free
iCloud.com.company.myApp_nonfree

Most apps accesses only that own default container. However it's reasonable to think that myApp_free and myApp_nonfree should use the same container. Then, say free user starts paying, the data would still be accessible. So myApp_nonfree would use the paying versions container for hassle-free upgrades.

My suspicion is that its just another simulator problem. A simulator with iOS 8+ will return a nil container if you are accessing (URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:containerIdentifier) with an iCloud account that has not migrated to iCloud Drive.